# How can I return a value from getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $("#search-box").keyup(function(){
            var filter = $(this).val();

            var req = {
                    action: 'getItem',
                    filter: filter              
                };

            this.getJSON('videos.php', req, function(serverData)
            {

            });
   });
```

I have above function which returns values. How can I return the *serverData*?

Comment: your variable `self` is not defined in this code.

Comment: and `this` will refer to the element that tiggered the event, are you meaning `jQuery.getJSON` ?

Comment: You need to use a Promise (a Deferred) in jQuery land. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: It should be jQuery.getJSON as @PatrickEvans suggested.

Comment: @GaryStorey, you dont need a promise, you can pass getJSON a success callback

Comment: @PatrickEvans true. Just my preference.

Comment: @aptlmsnkrdsm What do you mean by `return`? Wondering if this is a terminology issue or if you actually wanted to return a value from it. This distinction will affect whether or not it is a duplicate.

Comment: return is return man

Comment: Right... but what's confusing is i don't see in your code why you would think you need to return data from the getJSON. you didn't show how you intended to use the data or where you wanted to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
$("#search-box").keyup(function(){
   var filter = $(this).val();
   var that = this;
   var req = {
       action: 'getItem',
       filter: filter              
   };
   $.when( $.getJSON( "videos.php", req ) ).then(function( serverData, textStatus,jqXHR )
     {
        call_some_function_which_handles_response(serverData);
     });

});
```

Comment: This does not work because other function is not loaded when i call it. I get undefined 'function' error

Comment: $.when(...).then(...) is not needed.

Comment: but why it does not work?  I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Comment: you should rename call_some_function_which_handles_response into the function, which you want to handle received data.

Comment: i created another one like this.handleData but not working.

Comment: or substitute call_some_function_which_handles_response(serverData); with console.log (serverData); you will see data from the server on javascript console.

Comment: change this. to that